# Is it possible to knit just one code chunk and output the LaTeX code to the console?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX and doing the data analysis in R. I already have my tex files setup with the formatting I want and a R markdown file for my code. I only use R markdown, because of the improved sectioning and not to generate any sort of report from it. My normal workflow for making tables was to generate a regression table in R using `texreg` or `stargazer` and copy the LaTeX code to my tex file. But now I need to make a custom regression table and I have found the `kableExtra` package to have a simple syntax for making it look good using `booktabs`.

Is it possible to generate LaTeX code from only a single code chuck with the  `kableExtra` call without knitting my whole document and going into the generated .tex file to copy and paste the part for the table into my thesis?

I see that I am probably misunderstanding the idea behing knitr, but I am hesitant to change my workflow.

Comment: Just specify in `kable()` `format = "latex"`... you can do that straight from the console

Comment: I don't know why this didn't work for me before, but it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a concrete example:

```
sink("texy.txt")
iris[1:2, 1:5] %>% 
  kable(format = "latex") %>% 
  kable_styling(font_size = 14) %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "6cm") %>% 
  capture.output() %>%
  cat(sep = "\n")
sink()
```

Now I have the following in `texy.txt`:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering\begingroup\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{6cm}|r|r|r|l}
\hline
Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species\\
\hline
5.1 & 3.5 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
\hline
4.9 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\endgroup{}
\end{table}
```